# Link between jtf_notes from Advanced Collections and ra_customer_trx in Account Receivables

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

I am looking to get notes from advanced collections screen to be shown on  account receivables screen in oracle apps.
How can I do that.
Basically, I need to have a join between jtf_notes_vl and ra_customer_trx_all.

I found out on a support link which says that SOURCE_OBJECT_ID from JTF_NOTES is equal to the PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_ID in AR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULES_ALL. But that doesn't work . I get no records when I add this condition.

Can you please let us know a way in which I can have notes on AR screen.

Thanks you

Comment: Hi, I am a bit removed from EBS now, but this old forum post does a good job of identifying an Oracle Apps Form's source objects, http://www.oracleappsblog.com/index.php/forum/viewthread/17/#15. Oracle Application Framework is another story.  Also, it would not hurt to raise a service request to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The ids in jtf_notes_b point to JTF objects of the source_object_codes listed in jtf_objects_vl (navigation: CRM Administrator > Task an Escalation Manager > Setup > Objects Meta-data).

The jtf object definition has the table name that corresponds to each source_object_code:

```
select
count(*) count,
jnv.source_object_code,
jnv.source_object_meaning,
jov.from_table
from
jtf_notes_vl jnv,
jtf_objects_vl jov
where
jnv.source_object_code=jov.object_code(+)
group by
jnv.source_object_code,
jnv.source_object_meaning,
jov.from_table
order by count(*) desc
```